# MVC 3 Display data from different Models in the one View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the MVC 3 View I want to display a single Contract and a list of Claims, the user will be able to create a new claim. I have created a different view for Contract and Claims how can I merge these so that there is only one view.

---

Darin,

How do I pass an instance of MyViewModel as the view is looking for two strings?

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   MyViewModel myView = new MyViewModel ();
   return View(_repository.GetContract(id), myView); 
}
```

Thanks

---

I was using PartialViews Html but I don't see how to pass the model as a parameter.

Contract View
@model Portal.Models.Contracts
@using Portal.Models

Display data.

```
<div>
    @{
      Html.RenderPartial("_Claim", Portal.Models.Contracts); 

    }
</div>
```

I am getting an error CS0119: 'Models.Contracts' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context.

The data is bound to the Contract View here

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(_repository.GetContract(id);
}
```

How is the data bound to the `PartialView _Claim` which is of type `IEnumerable<Models.Claims>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a view model which will wrap those two models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public Claim[] Claims { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller action pass an instance of MyViewModel to the view and inside this view use display templates:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Contract)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Claims)
```

and then define display templates for the `Contract` and `Claim` models (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Contract.cshtml` and `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Claim.cshtml`).