# Reusable Code in MVC3 C#.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, helper, code-reuse

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  I have two views that display the same HTML table.  However, each View represents a different Model.  View 1 = "ProposalEdit", View 2 = "DocEdit".  Both the Proposal model and the Doc model have a property:

```
ICollection<Deliverable> Deliverables.
```

In each of the Edit Views, I display the Deliverables belonging to the Model of that View.  It's identical code in each of the Edit Views, only the Model behind the Edit Views is different.  So, there's a lot of duplicate code.

How can I modularize this in order to reduce the duplicate code?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7495623/438275

Comment: @Josh...interesting!  Looks like I would wrap Proposal and Doc inside the ViewModel and then create the one shared DisplayTemplate for the Deilverables table.  Is that how you read it?

Comment: @Mike, I don't even know that you want to wrap proposal and doc...just a shared display template for the ICollection<Deliverable> type should do it.

Comment: @KennyZ...I can see that.  I'll try both.

Comment: I actually think the issue is a little tougher?  We've been discussing a generic DisplayFor template.  It will apply to all PersistentGenericSet`1 lists.  I only want something specific to the Deliverables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mike, that is exactly what I would do.  The main point though is having the DisplayTemplates for each model.  Even a DateTime object could have a DisplayTemplate if you wanted to.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of using the DisplayTemplate for just the Deliverables model

```
@model ICollection<Deliverables>

@foreach (var deliverable in this.Model)
{
    @this.Html.DisplayFor(d => deliverable)
}
```

You would also, of course, have a template under `~\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Deliverables.cshtml` or for editing under `~\Shared\EditorTemplates\Deliverables.cshtml`

Comment: @Josh...I actually think the issue is a little tougher?  We've been discussing a generic DisplayFor template.  It will apply to all PersistentGenericSet`1 lists.  I only want something specific to the Deliverables.

Comment: Make the DisplayTemplate for Deliverables model then and loop through the collection. See my above edit.

Comment: @Josh...thanks for the update. I'll give it a run...question: how do I call that code above from my ProposalEdit view?